# make a table take its real height in grid

Tags: html, css, html-table, grid

I have two tables in a grid, The second table is less row than first. I wonder how can make second looks like first and don't let him take the whole height as the second, since they're not the same rows?

```css
.coords {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="coords">
    <table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>536594</td>
        <td>748725</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>335994</td>
        <td>349825</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>333594</td>
        <td>443025</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>331294</td>
        <td>446525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>237594</td>
        <td>449925</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>235594</td>
        <td>542825</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>137294</td>
        <td>547025</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>136694</td>
        <td>548525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>130694</td>
        <td>549125</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>037994</td>
        <td>640825</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>036194</td>
        <td>642525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>034094</td>
        <td>647525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>035394</td>
        <td>741625</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>039194</td>
        <td>743425</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>232694</td>
        <td>747625</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>339194</td>
        <td>842225</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>434994</td>
        <td>845025</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>536594</td>
        <td>748725</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this lines of `CSS`:

```css
.coords table {
    height: min-content;
}
```

by doing this, the `table` takes only the "less possible space taken by the element"

[image]

> for more details, you can watch this video: 
>  https://youtube.com/shorts/4iwQcvHYfWE?feature=share
> (creator: web dev semplified)

Comment: Thank you Anas, I don't know there is a value min-content property for height!